# Android - How do I change this findViewById to work?

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

[image: Image Link]

I'm trying to open a webpage through an app and this seems to be the problem.

`myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);`

I'm not sure what to change here.

Answer (score 4):

Its just a warning and your execution shouldn't be blocked.

Starting with SDK 26,  `findViewById` returns Generic type (`<T extends View> T findViewById(int id)`) hence the type cast using `(WebView)` is redundant.

**Instead of**

`myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);`

**Use**

`myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);`

You can also remove it for `FloatingActionButton` as follows:

`FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);`

**Note:** Clean and rebuild once you have done the changes. The compiler error is not due to this warning.

Answer (score 3):

It was just `lint warning` that you don't need to cast this to `WebView`. If you will not do anything, it will work but if you want to avoid this warning do like below:

**Current**:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

**Change to**:

```
myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

**Extra Tip**:

Just noticed in the screenshot you attached that same thing you need to change in case of `Toolbar` and `FloatingActionButton` as well.

Remove casting `(Toolbar)` and `(FloatingActionButton)`.

For more information about this type casting warning check [**this article**](https://medium.com/@abangkis/android-0-clean-up-casting-c30acec56cef).

---

**Compile time error**:

Above changes are not related to compilation error.

To fix the compilation error, try by **File** > **Invalid Caches/Restart**

Screenshot for `Invalid Caches/Restart`:
[image]